# Is there any way to get average values from an array when using a Twig template?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig, average

Is there any way of getting the average value of an array of value just inside a Twig template when using Symfony2?
I tried something like the following code but it doesn't work

```
{% set sumratings = 0 %}
{% set count = 0 %}
{% for rating in article.ratings %}
  {% set sumratings = sumratings + rating.value %}
{% endfor %}
AVG: {{  sumratings / article.ratings.count  }}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do it

```
{% set sumratings = 0 %}
{% for rating in article.ratings %}
  {% set sumratings = sumratings + rating.value %}
{% endfor %}
AVG: {{  sumratings / article.ratings|length }}
```

Assuming `rating.value` is an integer

Comment: Right man! This is the solution! So the **| length** filter is applied only to the last term (**b**) of the expression **a / b**. Fantastic, this is not explained inside the Twig docs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The length filter is just a way to get the size of the array.  It's analagous to using PHP's count() in the right place. You wouldn't do `$avg = count( $sum / $values );` right?  You'd do this `$avg = $sum / count( $values );`

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in way to do that. Creating your own twig extension that can do it is simple! You need to create a filter, which is very well doumented in the cookbook: [How to write a custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

Comment: I know that! I was looking about the possibility to use such a built-in twig functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is correct but horrible to use, right ?

It's simple:

```
    function arrayAverage($array)
    {
        if (!is_array($array)) return false;
        if (!count($array)) return 0;
        $avg=0;
        foreach ($array as $num) $avg+=$num;
        $avg/=count($array);
        return $avg;
    }


$twig->addFilter('arrayAverage', new Twig_Filter_Function('arrayAverage'));
```

Now you can just do like this in your twig templates:

```
{{ somearray | arrayAverage }}
{{ somearray | arrayAverage | number_format }}
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern Twig versions, there's a [`reduce()` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/reduce.html) that can simplify this work, a bit:

```
{% set myValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] %}
{% set average = (myValues | reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0)) / (myValues | length) %}

{{ average }} {# 3 #}
```

See [this fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/yce4ri)!